# Как изменить внешний вид корзины в теме storefront?

Tags: php, wordpress, cms

В общем есть сайт на wordpress + woocommerce и тема storefront, не получается изменить внешний вид корзины, которая находится в хедере, поменять местами элементы и т.д., в теме storefront есть такой код, можете помочь разобраться за что он отвечает:

```
    function storefront_cart_link_fragment( $fragments ) {
        global $woocommerce;

        ob_start();
        storefront_cart_link();
        $fragments['a.cart-contents'] = ob_get_clean();

        ob_start();
        storefront_handheld_footer_bar_cart_link();
        $fragments['a.footer-cart-contents'] = ob_get_clean();

        return $fragments;
    }

    function storefront_cart_link() {
    ?>
        <a class="cart-contents" href="<?php echo esc_url( WC()->cart->get_cart_url() ); ?>" title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'View your shopping cart', 'storefront' ); ?>">
            <span class="amount"><?php echo wp_kses_data( WC()->cart->get_cart_subtotal() ); ?></span> <span class="count"><?php echo wp_kses_data( sprintf( _n( '%d item', '%d items', WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count(), 'storefront' ), WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() ) );?></span>
        </a>
    <?php
}
```

интересно что, когда убрать функцию storefront_cart_link() то корзина пропадает, но редактировать код не получается, добавить, убрать или поменять местами спаны в функции ничего не дает, наперед большое спасибо тем, кто откликнется!

Comment: Часто разные элементы находятся не в одном шаблоне, а нескольких. Вам нужно найти эту связь. Есть ссылка на сайт? Возможно это можно сделать стилями. Но нужно видеть исходный код

Answer (score 0):

Этот код отвечает за вывод корзины и ее элементов:
корявая :) цифра 1 это сумма и кол-во товаров в корзине, а корявая 2 - это иконка корзины

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сумма:

```
    <span class="amount">
     <?php echo wp_kses_data( WC()->cart->get_cart_subtotal() ); ?>
    </span>
```

Кол-во товаров:

```
    <span class="count">
     <?php echo wp_kses_data( sprintf( _n( '%d item', '%d items', WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count(), 'storefront' ), WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() ) );?>
    </span>
```